# Session message not displayed while other session are displayed

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I have button save and delete, when i press save button, the session message appeared, but when i press delete button, session message not appeared

here admin_tools.php :

```
<?php require_once 'admin_process.php'; ?>
<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['msg'])) :?>
    <div class="text-center alert alert-<?=$_SESSION['msg_type']?>">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
    <?php 
        echo $_SESSION['msg'];
        unset($_SESSION['msg']) ;
     ?>
    </div>
 <?php endif ?>
```

admin_process.php:

```
include "config.php"; 

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $nama_staff = $_POST['nama_staff'];
    $user_staff = $_POST['user_staff'];
    $pw_staff = md5($_POST['pw_staff']);
    $cabang = $_POST['cabang']; 

    $tambah = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO staff(nama_staff,user_staff,pw_staff,cabang) VALUES('$nama_staff','$user_staff','$pw_staff','$cabang')");
    if ($tambah) {
        mysqli_query($conn,$tambah);
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Staff berhasil ditambahkan";
        $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "success";
        header('location:admin_tools.php');
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
    $id_staff = $_GET['delete'];
    $hapus = mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM staff WHERE id_staff=$id_staff");
    if ($hapus) {
        mysqli_query($conn,$hapus);
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Staff berhasil dihapus";
        $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "danger";
        header('location:admin_tools.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: On admin tool you echo the session then unset it

Comment: Are the records deleting as expected?

Comment: So, "Save" is POST and "Delete" is GET? Is that correct?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile but if i not unset, it will still appear even i refresh the page

Comment: is there a `session_start();` in `admin_tools.php` or `admin_process.php`?? You test if the session is set but no output if it is not?

Comment: @tshimkus yes the record are save and deleted correctly

Comment: @RamRaider yes session_start(); on admin.process only

Comment: @kerbholz yes save is POST, and delete is GET, but the session msg of save is work properly

Comment: you seem to have a loop of dependencies here... `admin_tools` includes the `admin_process` file and using `header` in `admin_process` you redirect to `admin_tools` and so on and so on....

Comment: if i remove `unset` session on page `admin.tools` both session worked properly, but when i refresh the page the session msg still appear

Comment: Is the `<a href` getting printed?

Comment: @KebabProgrammer yes, it printed close icon on session msg

Comment: What about this line of code `<div class="text-center alert alert-<?=$_SESSION['msg_type']?>">` Inspect element on the link printed, and see if `alert-msg_type` is getting printed as well